# Changing layer color with a button click

Tags: javascript, leaflet, carto-js

I am trying to change the color of my map layer when filter buttons are selected. So, the goal is: the user sees all of the data in one color. Then, when they click on a filter button, only a subset of the data is shown and in a different color.

I am looking for a command to call the previously defined styles when buttons are selected.

I have several map styles set up like this, each with a different polygon-fill (`bluestyle`, `redstyle`, etc):

```
<style type="cartocss/html" id="bluestyle">
        #blue{
          polygon-fill: #11799F;
          polygon-opacity: 0.7;
          line-color: #FFF;
          line-width: 0.5;
          line-opacity: 1;
        }


    </style>
```

Then, the code below (much of which is based on CartoDB's interactivity tutorial). Note I added "**" around the spot where I need to plug in this style change.

```
  function createSelector(layer) {
            var condition = "";
            var $options = $(".layer_selector").find("li");
            $options.click(function(e) {
                var $li = $(e.target);
                var selected = $li.attr('data');
                var type = $li.data('type');
                if (type === "cartocss") {
                    $options.removeClass('cartocss_selected');
                    if (selected !== "bluestyle") {
                        $li.addClass('cartocss_selected');                      
                    }
                    condition = $('#'+selected).text();
                    layer.setCartoCSS(condition);
                }  else {
                    $options.removeClass('sql_selected');
                    if (selected !== "") {
                        $li.addClass('sql_selected');
                    }
                    if (selected.indexOf('Button1') !== -1) {
                        **(some code that will change the style to redstyle)** ;
                    } else {

                    }
                    layer.setSQL("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + selected);
                } 
            });
        }
```

I am new to Javascript.